# Should I use Net::HTTP when I want to make POST request to an action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2, net-http

I have an action `create` and another action `register_and_create`. The first creates subscription and the seconds creates user and subscription. But I will have to copy the code of `create` action in `register_and_create` action. So is it good practice to use `Net::HTTP` to send POST request from `register_and_create` to `create` action?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a good practice.

If it was GET method, you should execute action code and return redirection to the second action.

For POST methods you should execute all code in `register_and_create` action. Sending `NET:HTTP` might cause a lot of problems - you have to make sure you assigned all HTTP headers, unnecessary requests comes to the server, etc.

If you found common parts of codes it might be good to move your code to `lib` module and use `include` in your controllers.

For example:

```
module RegistrationModule
  def create_user
    # your code goes here
  end
end

class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
  include RegistrationModule

  def register_and_create
    # subscribe
    create_user
  end

  def create
    create_user
  end
end
```